# Finding assemblies for a Universal or .NET Core app

Tags: .net-core, windows-10-universal

When I create a new Universal application (with VS 2017), I see "Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform" as a reference.  This seems to just signify that a host of actual assemblies are implied (I see System.AppContext.dll, System.Collections.dll, and many more in the project bin\x86\Debug folder after building the project).

1. Do these files exist somewhere on my machine and copied to the bin folder when building?  Or are they downloaded via Nuget when building? (I know that they are not the usual .NET Framework files in the usual .NET Framework locations).
2. How do I know which assemblies are implied by "Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform" without actually building?  (Visual Studio must get this information from somewhere since it knows which to add to the bin folder).
3. If you want to reflect on these assemblies for a specific project (for example, as part of a code refactoring process) without actually building the project, where would you find these assembles?

Comment: In my computer for example they are on ProgramFiles/ReferenceAssemblies/Microsoft etc. Try to check that location so we might help you answer your question

Comment: @AntoniosKatopodis: Nope - the only thing I have there is old framework 3 and 3.5 assemblies.

Answer (score 1):

1. UAP target platform (previously netcore50) (https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/standard/frameworks)
   it's located in '**C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NETCoreSDK**'
2. You can take a look at the nuget file '**C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NETCoreSDK\Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform\5.0.0\Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform.nuspec**' and see his dependencies or using nuget.org (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform/)
3. Most of his dependencies are located in the same folder (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NETCoreSDK), so you can take a look at the dlls (for example C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NETCoreSDK\System.Collections.Immutable\1.1.37\lib\dotnet\System.Collections.Immutable.dll)

Comment: Thanks for trying, but I don't have a NETCoreSDK folder in Microsoft SDKs. I'm using VS 2017 - looks like Microsoft is not putting these in one reliable place over different versions of VS?

Comment: My current work-around is to find all the dlls in the bin\x86\Debug folder and reflect on these (or bin\x64\Debug or bin\ARM\Debug, depending where I find them), but this does mean that a project has to be compiled for the dlls to be there.  I'm not happy that Microsoft has chosen to make this very obscure.  Previously, you could just read these from the project file.

Comment: You don't have ./Microsoft SDKs/NuGetPackages/Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform/ under Microsoft SDK's ?

Comment: Yes - I have *that* folder - does this contain the information I need?

Comment: Do you have a UWPNuGetPackages folder inside ?

Comment: No, just folders "5.0.0", "5.1.0", and "5.2.6".  It appears that there's not a lot of consistency to depend on - I'll still to my work-around.  +1 for the effort.